# struts 2 text tag with dynamic expression , how?

Tags: struts2

I need to supply the key dynamically from the action to the text tag

```
<s:text name="<%=talkToUsInfo.messageKey%>" />
```

but the name attribute on text tag is declared as  false ( not sure why ? )

How do i get something like this working without changing the tld in the jar file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Struts documentation](http://struts.apache.org/docs/text.html) says:

Instead, you should use the getText() method that you inherit when your Action extends XWork's ActionSupport:

```
<s:textfield name="lastName" label="getText('person.lastName')" />
```

So I used e.g.

```
<s:property value="getText('status' + #someObject.currentStatus)" />
```

instead of "s:text" and it worked.

Comment: this doesn't address the question at hand. The question was how to create your i18n key dynamicaly

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at OGNL

It might look like this

```
<s:text name="%{talkToUsInfo.messageKey}" />
```

Comment: link to [OGNL](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ognl.html) would be usefull

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `OGNL` and `s:text` and do not make a call to `getText` manually.
You usually define a fixed prefix while add the dynamic part to it, so some thing like this could be used:

```
<s:text name="%{'student.types.'+currencyType}" />
```

The only time which I used `getText` inside the `s:property` was something like this (which needs some `if/else` if you wanted to use `s:text` ):

```
<s:property value="shouldCancelIt.equals(\"0\") ? 
                           getText('label.yes'):getText('label.no')" />
```